# Scroll by dragging with mouse

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a scrollable panel but without the scrollbar and to scroll by dragging with mouse vertically... here is what somebody helped me to do so far.. :

```
 private void panel1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.AutoScroll = false;
    }

    private int ValidateChange(int change)
    {
        var padding = -1;
        if (change < 0)
        {
            var max = (from Control control in Controls select control.Top + control.Height + padding).Concat(new[] { int.MinValue }).Max();

            if (max < Height + Math.Abs(change))
            {
                return Height - max;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var min = (from Control control in Controls select control.Top).Concat(new[] { int.MaxValue }).Min();

            if (min > padding - Math.Abs(change))
            {
                return padding - min;
            }
        }
        return change;
    }

    private void HandleDelta(int delta)
    {
        var change = ValidateChange(delta);

        foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            control.Top += change;
        }

    }

    private void panel1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        HandleDelta(e.Delta);
        base.OnMouseWheel(e);
    }

    private Point _mouseLastPosition;

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            _mouseLastPosition = e.Location;
        }
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    public void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {            
            if ((MouseButtons & MouseButtons.Left) != 0)
            {
                var delta = e.Y - _mouseLastPosition.Y;
                HandleDelta(delta);
                _mouseLastPosition = e.Location;
            }
            base.OnMouseMove(e);

    }
```

but it goes just too fast..
EDIT: the dragging by mouse looks a little bit weird i dont know why and when I try to use mouse wheel it bugs and gives me this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Core.dll at this line `var max = (from Control control in Controls select control.Top + control.Height + padding).Concat(new[] { int.MinValue }).Max();`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me. It keeps a padding of 10 pixels on all controls. Try it out and just modify it to your needs.

Let me know if something is missing that you needed.

```
public class ScrollablePanel : Panel {
    private Point _mouseLastPosition;

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
            _mouseLastPosition = e.Location;
        }
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    private int ValidateChange(int change) {
        var padding = -1;
        if (change < 0) {
            var max = (from Control control in Controls select control.Top + control.Height + padding).Concat(new[] { int.MinValue }).Max();

            if (max < Height + Math.Abs(change)) {
                return Height - max;
            }
        }
        else {
            var min = (from Control control in Controls select control.Top).Concat(new[] { int.MaxValue }).Min();

            if (min > padding - Math.Abs(change)) {
                return padding - min;
            }
        }
        return change;
    }

    private void HandleDelta(int delta) {
        var change = ValidateChange(delta);

        foreach (Control control in Controls) {
            control.Top += change;
        }

    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
        if((MouseButtons & MouseButtons.Left) != 0) { 
            var delta = e.Y - _mouseLastPosition.Y;
            HandleDelta(delta);
            _mouseLastPosition = e.Location;
        }
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e) {
        HandleDelta(e.Delta);
        base.OnMouseWheel(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The mouseMove and mouse down actually the dragging by mouse scroll works... but when i use the mouse wheel it just freezes and can't do anything after that..... also I changed the padding to -1 because that's how I like it... so mouse wheel doesn't work properly

Comment: when I try to scroll with mouse wheel it gives me this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Core.dll at this line `var max = (from Control control in Controls select control.Top + control.Height + padding).Concat(new[] { int.MinValue }).Max();`

Comment: Sounds like a linq problem. Concat can actually cause problems like that. I will edit my answer and remove the linq part

Comment: still not working getting this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll at this line: `foreach (Control control in Controls)` in `GetMax`

Comment: Ok. Sound strange that this should give a StackOverflowException, but i will make it more simple and add some protection. If you still get the error after my latest change could you check the Call Stack and see if it somehow gets called multiple times? I cant reproduce the error? Can you try to explain how you get the error? Could you show all the code in the project or make a simple example and see if the error still occurs? I will make an update now..

Comment: https://github.com/cristicretan/OutfitPick/blob/master/Clothes%20Pick/Form2.cs here is my full form2 cs code... got the same error but in the for at `Controls.Count`

Comment: the controls[i] stays at 1 all the time and the control[i].Height just goes to 1000 ( 1000= panel1.Height) over and over again so yeah it's an endless loop

Comment: Thanks for the code. Now i see the problem. I made a class called ScrollablePanel to make it easier for you. But you copied the code into the form and the it dont work. If you take the code (i have reverted it back to the original code) and paste the class into a new file in your project. And then go to your design mode and remove your panel and replace it with ScrollablePanel (which should shove up in the top of all controls in the toolbox) and then use that panel everything should work. Let me know if you need help putting it together :)

Comment: but how do I use it that way?

Comment: yep it said failed to load scrollable panel it will be removed from the toolbox

Comment: Here. I changed it for you. This is your code with the ScrollablePanel. Download it here: https://expirebox.com/download/1ed09f6df0841ac37a880dd7c966008e.html  (Link only valid 24h, but for all others reading this, it is the same code as in the answer just inserted into the OPs code). I made changes in the Form2 code + design code and added a new class (ScrollablePanel).

Comment: wow you are awesome, but for my information how did you changed it that fast?

Comment: Downloaded your code from github and added the ScrollablePanel class and then just changed Panel into ScrollablePanel in the design Mode and removed all the code from the ScrollablePanel Code that was pasted and put Dock=Fill. Then tested the code and might have done some more changed i dont remember now to make sure it worked. Easy when you know the new code i guess.. Please mark it as accepted if it works :)

Comment: Hello, there is one more problem with your  panel... it ends exactly where my last button is... and I want to have somethin like a padding of 10 pixels...

Answer (score 6):

The posted code only 'scrolls' or rather moves the Panel **horizontally**. For a vertical scrolling effect change this:

```
   Panel pa = ss as Panel; pa.Left = pa.Left + ee.X - pPt.X;
```

to this:

```
   Panel pa = ss as Panel; pa.Top = pa.Top + ee.Y - pPt.Y;
```

To make any sense the 'scrolled' or 'moved'  panel also should be higher than the enclosing form, so change the sizes, maybe like this:

```
    f2.Size = new Size(400, 300);
    ..
    pan.Size = new Size(400, 600);
```

And the Buttons should be placed vertically as well, so change:

```
    b.Left = (b.Width + 12) * (i - 1);
```

to

```
    b.Top= (b.Height + 12) * (i - 1);
```

You also nmade a mistake when copying from the comments: This:

```
 pan.Parent = f2;
```

should be the last line in the loop. Adding event handlers in the loops means that also the `MouseMove` is called 10 times distance of the movement is also tenfold.

Here is what is looks like, when coded correctly:

[image]

To make the `MouseWheel` work you can code it maybe  like this:

```
 pan.MouseWheel += (ss, ee) =>
 {
      Panel pa = ss as Panel;
      pa.Top += ee.Delta > 0 ? 10 : -10;
 };
```

**Update** Looks like you also want to limit the scrolling so that neither top nor bottom can move into the display area. Here is a check to achieve that; the trick is to first do the check and only then do the moving:

```
            if (ee.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left))
            {
                Panel pa = ss as Panel;

                int newTop =  pa.Top + ee.Y - pPt.Y;

                if ((newTop <= pan.Top && newTop + pan.Height > f2.ClientSize.Height) ||
                    (newTop >= pan.Top && newTop <= 0))
                {
                    if (newTop <= pan.Top && newTop + pan.Height > f2.ClientSize.Height) 
                        newTop = f2.ClientSize.Height - pan.Height;
                    pa.Top = newTop;
                }
            }
```

The `MouseWheel` code should be checked and limited in a similar way!

Note: The correct panel height is of the essence here. My original example didn't take care of that, as no scroll limit was asked for. You could get it like this dynamically:

```
int panHeight = pan.Controls.Cast<Control>().Select(x => x.Bottom).Max();
pan.Height = panHeight;  // maybe add a small gap here..?
```

Comment: I made a video and posted it here to show you how it works.. it's the same code.. https://vimeo.com/194139497

Comment: I found your bug and I have added a video of how the code works here.

Comment: So if I put the mouse move outsite the loop it should work?

Comment: Yeah It works now.... but I already have some buttons in my form i want to scroll on does it work for them too? Also I want to set a maximum point of scroll on the Top side and on the down side..

Comment: I have added code for the mousewheel. Which part you want to scroll and how far it will scroll is up to you. Only the Panel can move, so they all need to be on it. Setting limits can be done either by sizing the panel or by adding conditions to the code.. I may help to add a color to the panel back color for testing..

Comment: so it will scroll only in the existing panel right? I mean only from position 0 to it's max size not higher or to be a loop scroll..

Comment: No 'loop scroll' if you mean that buttons come back in from the other end. That would require a completely different approach.. You need to learn to ask question in a more complete way. Also: I at first didn't notice but deducing from the comments by @KMoussa it looks as if you have abused an old question of yours and made it in into a completely different one. That is against the SO rules and will make matters worse if you are under a question ban!! Don't do that again. Here only a few comments are out of place but if there had been any answer this would need to be reverted by the mods!!!

Comment: Yeah, that's right but I couldn't ask questions at the time... also.. I see you make it able to scroll up too but I want it to scroll only from where the buttons start to where the buttons end..not more than that..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129683/discussion-between-c-cristi-and-taw).

Comment: Did you saw my message?

Comment: Wheel works perfect on the top side but on the bottom side not really with pan.Top = pan.Height - f2.Height; the buttons dissapear like this... also How do I tell him not to move if it's too high by dragging... it looks weird probably because of the mousedown event.. but can;t figure out what;s wrong

Comment: Do set a color to the bckcolr so you can see the actual size of the panel!! My code make it to hight, therefor the bottom stop won't work. Then correct the panel height or check for the bottom Button.Bottom

Comment: I did set a color to the panel, I'll try

Comment: I think what happens it's that it gives me the panel1.Height - button8.Height (the last button) on the top of panel and can't scroll from there.. I did go like this : 
                `if (panel1.Top < panel1.Height - button8.Bottom) panel1.Top = panel1.Height - button8.Bottom;`
**This is at the mouse wheel**

Comment: Now I tried it like this and it kind of works but when I go too "low" it brings me to the top again and I want to stay at the bottom...`if (panel1.Top > 0) panel1.Top = 0;
                else if (panel1.Bottom < panel1.Parent.Height) panel1.Top = panel1.Height;`

Comment: Still doesn't work.. the upper part still goes above but the too low said doesn't go "till the end" i mean until the max size of panel.. goes over the last button..

Answer (score 0):

I tested all solutions published here, but none of them worked for me.

My situation is that I'm developing a Print Designer in an application for different printouts. This Print Designer offers zooming of the printout and dragging of the print elements on the printout. I wanted to offer dragging the printout itself when pressing the left mouse button on an empty space of the printout.

My form has a Panel (pnlWorkspace) on it with AutoScroll = true. In that I show multiple panels inside of each other

1. pnlBorder with BackgroundColor = Black is 2 pixels larger than the paper size
2. pnlReceipt is inside pnlBorder at Location 1, 1, Size 2px smaller than pnlBorder, and BackgroundColor = Gainsboro
3. pnlPrintArea with Location and Size set according to the real Printer Margins and BackgroundColor = White;

Because of the paper size and zooming the panels may be larger that the containing panel with AutoScroll set to True.

My very simple working solution without any problems (even the Mouse's ScrollWheel still works) uses just a very few lines of code now. First I created a variable directly in the From:

```
    private Boolean dragScroll = false;
```

Then I added 3 Routines:

```
    private void Panel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            clickPos = PointToClient(MousePosition);
            clickPos.X -= pnlWorkspace.AutoScrollPosition.X;
            clickPos.Y -= pnlWorkspace.AutoScrollPosition.Y;
            dragScroll = true;
            pnlBorder.Cursor = pnlReceipt.Cursor = pnlPrintArea.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;
        }
    }

    private void Panel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) && (dragScroll))
        {
            mousePos = PointToClient(MousePosition);
            pnlWorkspace.AutoScrollPosition = new Point((clickPos.X - mousePos.X), (clickPos.Y - mousePos.Y));
        }
    }

    private void Panel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dragScroll = false;
        pnlBorder.Cursor = pnlReceipt.Cursor = pnlPrintArea.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

Then I connected those Routines to the Panels pnlBorder, pnlReceipt, and pnlPrintArea by selecting them in the Properties window. And that's all there is to it :•)

Here's a video showing the Print Designer's functionality: https://youtu.be/frjWn5bOyo8